# Header colour change from array on page refresh (Squarespace)

Tags: squarespace

I believe I am really close but don't have the knowledge to know where I am going wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//colour change on refresh
var colorArray = ["#003D44", "#096570", "#164487", "#FFFF99", "#2252A0", "#72220D"];
const headerr = document.querySelector('.header-announcment-bar-wrapper')
function getRandomColor() {
  return colorArray[Math.random() * colorArray.length | 0];
}

console.log(getRandomColor());

window.addEventListener('load', ()=> {
    headerr.style.backgroundColor * getRandomColour
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to **FOOTER** code injection:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Randomly set background color of Announcement Bar Wrapper.
  const headerABW = document.querySelector('.header-announcement-bar-wrapper');
  const colorArray = ["#003D44", "#096570", "#164487", "#FFFF99", "#2252A0", "#72220D"];
  headerABW.style.backgroundColor = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];
</script>
```

It's important that it be added to the footer code injection so that the element is present when the code is executed. That removes the need for an event listener.

The function declaration is also unnecessary; the background color can be set directly.

You also had a typo; a missing 'e' in 'announcement'.

It is also worth noting that the color may not change with each refresh if it randomly selects the same color as it was previously. There are methods to store the last selected color and ensure that a different color is loaded on page refresh.

Comment: As usual it seems as if I was overcomplicating the issue.

Code injected and working perfectly. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad to help, and glad that it worked on your end as well. Changes to the Squarespace platform over the years (in particular, how it loads content) have indeed made it more difficult to find and adapt even simple code solutions. As always, consider accepting and upvoting answers if/as appropriate.